# Was Paul Manafort permitted to leave the country before his indictment?

Tags: united-states

The rumours of the indictment of Paul Manafort was all over the news and media days (or even months) before we was formally indicted. So it would be a fair guess that Manafort had a pretty good idea it was coming.

If so, then why didn't he just leave the country to another country (preferably to a country which didn't have extradition treaty with the US) before it became formal.

Would he have been permitted to leave if he showed up at the airport?

Comment: Can you cite the first fact. The second paragraph asks us to look to his personal motivations. Probably he didn't want to live in Russia or a country with no extradition treaty, he has family and friends in the US. The last paragraph asks a legal question.

Comment: The obvious is that he doesn't think he is guilty. Idictments are not convictions

Comment: What's the point of acquiring ill-gotten gains if you leave them all behind and flee? Plus, given his position, he probably expects a full pardon to be already written, awaiting a signature, at the first sign of him turning on Trump. No need to flee.

Comment: The legal aspect of this question would be much better suited at law.SE I think, as it's only marginally connected to politics.

Comment: You don't need an airport to leave the US.

Answer (score 4):

Leaving the country would have been a bad option even if he was allowed to do it. Attempting to flee the country when you are going to be/are indicted is a sure way to make it easier for prosecution to prove your guilt. The countries that don't have extradition treaties with the U.S. also don't tend to be the greatest places to live even if you are rich. It's also not enough to just leave the country, you need to have your assets leave the country as well to a place they can't be frozen by the U.S. or their allies. Living in exile isn't really as glamorous as its portrayed in most media.

Being indicted also isn't that big of deal for someone like Manafort. He can afford enough lawyers to have a really good chance of being found not guilty assuming a trial ever occurred. The timeline between being indicted and actually going to trial would likely be years in this case, and Manafort is almost guaranteed to be granted bail. A plea deal is the most likely outcome that won't result in spending a lifetime in prison.

TLDR: Spending a handful of years in prison, that you probably can arrange extremely nice treatment, is far more preferable than a lifetime of exile.

Comment: He's already been granted a 10 million dollar bail.

Comment: It doesn't prove his guilt as you say. It surely would make his guilt more believable.

Comment: Although this answer may contain true facts, it seems to answer a question about pros/cons of leaving/staying. But it does not seem to answer the original question about whether or not he was **permitted** to leave the country.

Comment: @bytebuster: But that question is nonsense. _Of course_ he was permitted to leave - he had a passport, and anyone with a valid passport can travel to wherever abroad so long as they comply with the host country's requisite Visa rules. The only real question is whether he should have done so.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy, true. Bad questions (incl. poorly worded ones) lead to bad answers. If we assume that the OP wanted to ask something other than what they have actually asked, be sure that 10 different people would have 10 different opinions about what *"the only real question is"*. And we end up with 10 (bad) answers, each answering their own *"the only real question"*. We have to **improve the question first**.